# Android HLS or MPEG-DASH javascript

Tags: javascript, http-live-streaming, mpeg-dash

Trying to stream to android devices I am having to know HLS is not such a robust streaming option on Android devices. Is there a way to determine if the browser supports MPEG-DASH and if not provide an alternative HLS implementation through javascript?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On Android >= 4.0 you can make use of the MSE for a MPEG-DASH playout (if you are using chrome). There are some HTML5/JS based DASH player solutions available, like [dash.js](http://dashif.org/reference/players/javascript/1.2.0/index.html) or [bitdash](http://www.dash-player.com/#home), which will also work on Android. I know that bitdash can even switch to a Flash fallback (if Flash is installed on the device) to support DASH on older Android versions.

You can check if your browser/OS/device combination supports DASH by using scripts like [Radiant MediaLyzer](http://www.radiantmedialyzer.net/).

On Android > 4.1 [ExoPlayer](https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer), which is a native App for adaptive streaming including MPEG-DASH playout, can be a good choice as well.